# Set a timeout for GCD operation

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I have an app that allows users to obtain stream gauge info via web service. In rural areas, network connections may be slow or nonexistent. I would like to set a timeout on the fetch operation but am not really sure how to go about it. Here is the fetch operation:

```
[self.view addSubview:hud];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
    stateGauges = [[GaugeList alloc] initWithStateIdentifier:stateIdentifier andType:nil];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        [hud removeFromSuperview];
    });
});
```

If I wanted this operation to timeout (10 seconds), causing the activity indicator to disappear and return the app to normal functioning, how might I go about that?

Thanks!

Comment: What is/does `GaugeList`?

Comment: Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/21009779/629118

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**blocks can't be canceled, they need to check themselves**.

the bad & hard way (DYI)

you need a separate queue that just has a timeoutblock end where, on timeout you set a BOOL to isCancel. In the other block you check

#### the GOOD & easy way

use NSOperationQueue & NSOperation APIs -- :)

There, NSOperationQueue also won't kill long running operations automatically but the general infrastructure is in place and it is easier to accomplish

e.g. the operation could do it on its own... see AFNetworkingOperations for one way of doing it

Comment: NSOperationQueue also requires that the operation checks for cancellation (if it has already been started). It won't "kill" a long running call `[[GaugeList alloc] initWithStateIdentifier...` (whatever that is).

Comment: too much effort. ill delete it instead if the answer isn't helpful